# How to animate a CGContext created in a UIView using swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, xcode7.1beta

I have created a image as CGContext in a class which is a subclass of UIView class. I need to know how to animate this image. I need to animate this image such that it moves along a circle/arc.

the image is created using the following code:

```
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()  
let rad = CGRectGetWidth(valueRect)/0.08  
let endAngle = CGFloat(2*M_PI)
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 10, UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.35).CGColor)
CGContextAddArc(ctx, CGRectGetMidX(valueRect), CGRectGetMidY(valueRect), rad, 0, endAngle, 1)
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx,UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillPath(ctx)
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.1)
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

I need to animate the circle image in `ctx` along an arc of certain radius with a certain start and end angle. Can anyone suggest a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to animate the view that displays the image. You can easily animate a view along a path using keyframe animation.

Comment: Thanks matt....The view contains other elements also... A class , subclass of UIView, contains an image shown above and , i have many lines drawn in that view.... so i cannot animate the view itself. if so can you provide me  an example?

Comment: I don't know how far you want to go with this. Here's a downloadable example project that shows how to animate a CGContext drawing: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch04p165customAnimatableProperty3/Triangle